# difference between keeping database in app_data and connecting to an external database

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ado.net

I want to know what is the difference between creating a database in app_data and connecting to a external database.

i went through this question.but i am not clear idea.

[What's the difference between the database inside App_Data folder vs connecting to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000848/whats-the-difference-between-the-database-inside-app-data-folder-vs-connecting-t)

what is the advantages/disadvantage of using each type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while developing, you will not see a big difference between both of them,  but as many know, SQL server express has some limitations ( like supporting only 1 CPU) and this with intensive websites will affect the overall performance.

if your model is to develop locally using SQL express, then take the DB from your App_Data folder to a full SQL server instance( say on your hosting server) then no worries, but hosting your website and let SQL server express manage your end users, may result in bad performance solution.