# SQL Server Express database is file or like normal mysql database which is behind a mysql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, app-data

I would like to know if I create a database which is in asp.net mvc4 `app_data` folder will be like MS Access database or will be like MySQL database which can be used calling the MySQL server?

What is different between SQL Server Express and normal SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your database in app_data folder of the application look at the [Database in App_data folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728467/difference-between-keeping-database-in-app-data-and-connecting-to-an-external-da) which might help you.

About SQL server vs SQL Server express, Few of the differences are MS SQL Server is capable of handling more number of concurrent users/trasactions as compare to SQL express.

SQL Express has a database size limitation upto 4 GB

SQL express can not schedule jobs, 1 CPU and does not have advance features like SSIS

Comment: SQL Server Express versions **2008 R2** and **2012** support up to **10 GB** database size